# htaccess RewriteRule The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my first time trying to write htaccess rules. My target is to make all relative links to be redirected to absolute. To begin i was testing:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule gallery\.php$ http://www.domain.com/sample/gallery.php
RewriteRule info\.php$ http://www.domain.com/sample/gallery.php
```

The first rule makes Firefox throw the error "The page isn't redirecting properly" when I click on the link, while the second rule works fine. The idea for the future was to write a rule like,

```
RewriteRule catchAllRelativeLinks$ http: //www.domain.com/sample/$1
```

but if I can't make the first rule work I don't think I will find how to make the real rule.

EDIT:
to avoid the endless loop can't i try to understand if i am on the first or second istance by catching a variable ? some ideas i tried (and faild):

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^gallery\.php$ http://www.domain.com/gallery.php?a [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(\?something)$
RewriteRule ^gallery\.php$ http://www.domain.com/gallery.php?something [R=302,L]
```

or with an environment variable,

thanks again

Comment: What is the first intended to match?  is it meant for `/gallery.php` to redirect into `/sample/gallery.php`?  If so, it should include `^` as in `^gallery\.php$`

Comment: U can checkout this explanation and guide for the same (: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21754308/5465790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule you have results in an endless loop. `mod_rewrite` isn't all that great at making relative links absolute. That should be done in the HTML. For example, turning

```
<a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
```

into

```
<a href="/sample/gallery.php">Gallery</a>
```

However, the second rule works because it does something `mod_rewrite` does extremely well, and that's redirecting from one page or URL to another. For more information on this please see, the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html).

Comment: To avoid the endless loop can't i catch IS SUBREQ or throw and catch a param ?something ? i edited the question.

Comment: Yeah, it seems one could make it redirect only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this link for detailed explanation.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

This worked for me (:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    # Check for POST Submission | 
    # Because POST parameters aren't retained on a redirect.
    # You can omit that line if you want to make sure that all POST submissions are secure   
    # (any unsecured POST submissions will be ignored)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$

    # Forcing HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    # Pages to Apply
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^something_secure [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^something_else_secure
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```